# Left-align list items where centered headers begin

Tags: html, css

I have 4 centered headers and i'd like to be able to list items underneath each header. I'd like for these to be first centered to begin where the centered headers begin, and then left aligned.

I can't really post all the code to make is display how it is in my application, but I'll post the snippet and a picture:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3 text-center">
    <h5>Header 1</h5>
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li>Aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
      <li>bbb</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span3 text-center">
    <h5>Header 2</h5>
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li>1111</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>111111111111111</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span3 text-center">
    <h5>Header 3</h5>
    <ul class="unstyled">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span3 text-center">
    <h5>Header 4</h5>
    <ul class="unstyled">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like my list items to begin where the red line starts:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to move the contents of the list over to the left, you could adjust the  padding like this:

```
ul {
   padding-left: 18px;
}
```

Or if you want to get rid of the bullets as well so it looks like the picture you posted then

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Should work.